# What does mov qword rbx, '//bin/sh' mean?

Tags: linux, shellcode

I follow this [tutorial](http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/writing-64-bit-shellcode-part-2-removing-null-bytes-0161591/) in order to understand how the 64 bits shellcode work.

So, I code this shellcode and it's works:

```
BITS 64

xor rax, rax
mov qword rbx, '//bin/sh'
shr rbx, 0x8
push rbx
mov rdi, rsp
push rax
mov rdx, rsp
push rdi
mov rsi, rsp
mov al, 59
syscall
```

I understand all of this code except two instructions:

```
mov qword rbx, '//bin/sh'
shr rbx, 0x8
```

I understand that a qword is a data of size 64 bits but when I remove qword the shellcode doesn't work. Why I need to add qword?

And after the instruction shr, my strings should be looks like '%00//bin/s' no? Why not use shl instead of shr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand that a qword is a data of size 64 bits but when I remove qword the shellcode doesn't work. Why I need to add qword?

Because you're moving a qword constant. When you type `'//bin/sh'` you're expressing an 8-char array. By prefixing with qword you're instructing the assembler to treat the right hand operand as an inline 64-bit integer. By default it will probably treat it as a pointer to that string, or some other behaviour.

> And after the instruction shr, my strings should be looks like '%00//bin/s' no?

Integers on x86 architecture processors are stored as [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). If your compiler took it literally, your string would be encoded in ASCII as follows:

```
/  /  b  i  n  /  s  h
2f 2f 62 69 6e 2f 73 68
```

Which you can also show in the following instruction:

```
mov rbx, 0x2f2f62696e2f7368
```

This encodes as follows:

```
48 BB 68 73 2F 6E 69 62 2F 2F
```

We can split this up into 3 sections:

```
48        BB                     68 73 2F 6E 69 62 2F 2F
|         |                      |---------------------|
 \         \                             literal
  64-bit     B8 = MOV instr
  prefix        + reg operand
                + r/m operand
```

In this case the mov instruction byte (`BB`) also contains a 7-bit field which describes the register we're moving into (`rbx`) and the type of right-hand operand (literal).

But note carefully: the literal is *not* in the same order as the ASCII representation we saw above. Instead it is reversed due to little-endianness.

The problem here, of course, is this can't possibly be what happens in your shellcode. If the name was reversed in the bytes then the function you call would see `hs/nib//` and fail. Instead, your assembler is smart enough to realise that you want those ASCII characters in byte-order, which means it really encodes the following instruction:

```
mov rbx, 0x68732f6e69622f2f
```

This produces the following encoded instruction:

```
48 BB 2F 2F 62 69 6E 2F 73 68
```

As you can see, the `//` comes first (`2F 2F`) in the byte-order representation.

> Why not use shl instead of shr?

You do both. Your code is missing an instruction, which can be seen in the tutorial. After the `shl rbx, 0x8` there immediately follows a `shr rbx, 0x8`.

Their explanation does it justice:

> After shifting 0x08 to the left (think of each numeric placeholder in the string as a 4, so moving 8 bytes over actually moves us two spaces) pushes the 11 right off the end. Now we have this:
>
> 0x68732f6e69622f00
>
> Then we put it back like before by using shr by the same value, and we get this:
>
> 0x0068732f6e69622f
>
> This successfully gives us our string terminated by a nullbyte without generating a single nullbyte in the machine code.

The first slash is simply a sacrificial character which gets discarded during the `shl`.

The reason for this trick instead of just loading the null in the first place or masking the rightmost byte with zero is that it requires no null-bytes in the exploit payload, which is very useful if input is ignored after a null (e.g. if a string is being copied with strcpy).